# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 error

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I've got some simple code that is running in a block (completion block).  In the completion block I want to display an UIAlertView if the process in the block returns FALSE.  As a best practice you are not supposed to call any UI methods in a background thread so I am using dispatch_get_main_queue to display the UIAlertView.  This works okay except that I receive a wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 error message when the cancel button in the UIAlert view is pressed.

The code is below.  I'm not sure how else to do this and to the best of my knowledge the code looks like it's correct and should work but obviously there is a problem with it.  I was hoping that another set of eyes could help locate the issue.

```
    __block bool theResult;
    [self.mbProgressHUD showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
      theResult = [someClass someMethodThatReturnsTRUEorFALSE];
    } completionBlock:^{
      [self.mbProgressHUD removeFromSuperview];
      if (theResult) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          UIAlertView *theAlert....
          [theAlert show];
        });
      };
    }];
```

Everything seems to work okay except when the OK button is selected in the UIAlert.  I receive wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 100040003 error message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`removeFromSuperview` directly affects the view hierarchy, which counts as touching the UI. You can't touch the UI from a background thread. You need to put `[self.mbProgressHUD removeFromSuperview];` onto the main queue as well.

Comment: I had also tried that.  I had wrapped everything in the completionBlock in a dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_mainqueue(), ^{}) block.  Same problem.  I just tried it again and I receive the same result.

Comment: Is this entire snippet on a background thread? `showAnimated:...` would need to be on the main thread as well.